# How to sync notification and ringtone volumes when pressing up/down buttons on Galaxy S6?

Tags: volume-control, samsung-galaxy-s-6, volume

When using the volume keys on the galaxy S6 it changes the volume of the ring tone only. However, when pressing the volume buttons I would expect the volume of both the ring tone and notifications to be affected.

Is there a way to link those two volumes in a way that both are changed when pressing the hardware volume buttons ?

My previous phone was a S3 and the volume keys were setting both volumes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything built in to the Android O/S to link/sync ringtone and notification volumes (for the Galaxy S6 anyways).

The best I've found (and currently using) is **Volume Sync Pro by Plextab Software**.
It does exactly what you want with the up/down volume rocker button. It's a paid app though.

I've tried these free apps and they did not work for me.

- volume Control + by Coffee Break Apps
- Volume Sync by Jesta's Funhouse

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think needing a paid app to achieve that is really bad though. It should be the default behavior of the volume button.